# Preventing user accesing Node.js application code

Tags: security, node.js

Assuming a user has access to all files within the public_html directory. Doesn't this mean they could have access the a node.js application code within it? Surely this is a massive security risk.

What is the normal way of handling this? Would you user files permissions to restrict the file, or place the node directory outside of the public_html and reference it somehow? If so, how?

Many thanks for any answers given!!

Comment: you dont have to put the node.js app in a public directory...

Comment: so if I needed to make a call to the application in order to retrieve some JSON, how would you recommend doing this? Would I just use the web url and append the port number node is running on?

Comment: yes, this is how it works. The app is listening on a port in your server. Like Apache or the FTP service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your server scripts should live outside `public_html`.  Only files that you want to make available to the public should be placed under `public_html`.

Your node server script can refer to the `"./public_html"` or `"../public_html"` folder if it is stored in or above the folder containing the script, or it can even refer to `"/path/to/public_html"` if it is stored elsewhere on your filesystem.